# regex for matching http and www urls in a php string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Here is the code i am using

```
function parseURL($text) {
    $regex = "#\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))#iS";
    preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches);
    foreach($matches[0] as $pattern){
        $text = str_replace($pattern, "<a href=\"$pattern\" target=\"_blank\">$pattern</a> ", $text);   
    }
    return $text;
}
```

For some reason my regex is outputting the following results: (bold = linked)

> **www.domain.com**
>
> http://**www.domain.com**
>
> **http://domain.com**

so it works fine except if it contains both http and www at which point it only links from the www part onward.

any idea why?

**EDIT**

For anyone reading this requiring the fix, here is the working code thanks to  ***Wiktor Stribiżew***..

```
function parseURL($text) {
    $regex = "@\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\(\w+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))@i";
    $subst = "<a href='$0' target='_blank'>$0</a>";
    $text = preg_replace($regex, $subst, $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Why are you replacing matches? Just use `preg_replace` directly. Also, `S` makes no sense here (even if you meant to use `s`, DOTALL). See [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/5hj7fX).

Comment: Is there any reason, why you don't use http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php?

Comment: @Anant its when there is more than one url in the $text string

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew - Ah yeah, i've been trying for that long i forgot i was using str_replace which was my problem! Thanks, my issue is now solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to first collect matches and then replace each one by one. Use a `preg_replace` directly and use a `$0` backreference to refer to the whole match from the replacement pattern.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/5hj7fX):

```
$re = '@\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\(\w+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))@i';
$str = "www.domain.com\nhttp://www.domain.com\nhttp://domain.com";
$subst = '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a> ';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

Output:

```
<a href="www.domain.com" target="_blank">www.domain.com</a> 
<a href="http://www.domain.com" target="_blank">http://www.domain.com</a> 
<a href="http://domain.com" target="_blank">http://domain.com</a>
```